# Stacked column chart not getting as expected in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, stacked-chart

I am plotting a sound sensor data chart based on following table in PowerBi.

[image: datatable]

The expected graph should be like this

[image]

But when I tried to plot it in PowerBi I am getting the graph as follows
[image]

I can't change Y axis graph and it showing the sum of the columns. How can I set the readings as shown in the actual graph.

Here is the settings image

[image]

The Color column condition is

```
Color = IF ([Content.Leq] < VALUE([Content.AverageAmbientNoise]),"blue",if ([Content.Leq] >= VALUE([Content.AverageAmbientNoise]) && [Content.Leq] < 85,"yellow",if ([Content.Leq] >= 85,"red")))
```

Is it possible to create the exact graph? If anybody provide the logic that will be very helpful

Comment: You will not be able to recreate the graph you showed with a stacked bar/column chart in power bi

Answer (score 0):

You should add the color values as a calculated column, this will add the colors in the visualization.

Turning on "data labels" will show the values of each subcategory:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an exampe for color column?